# Two DataTables merge with different PrimaryKey set

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, merge

I Have two datatables as follows

```
TableA
-------------------------------------------
ParamId   | Code   | Val   | date_time
-------------------------------------------
1         A1       5.6     02.04.2014 00:00
1         A1       10      02.04.2014 01:00
1         A1       5.9     02.04.2014 02:00
1         A1       8       02.04.2014 03:00
1         A1       7       02.04.2014 04:00
1         A1       12      02.04.2014 05:00


TableB
-------------------------------------------
ParamId   | Code   | Val   | date_time
-------------------------------------------
1         A2       5.6     02.04.2014 00:00
1         A2       10      02.04.2014 01:00
1         A2       5.9     02.04.2014 02:00
1         A2       8       02.04.2014 03:00
1         A2       7       02.04.2014 04:00
1         A2       12      02.04.2014 05:00

Expected result:
-------------------------------------------
ParamId   | Code   | Val   | date_time
-------------------------------------------
1         A1       5.6     02.04.2014 00:00
1         A1       10      02.04.2014 01:00
1         A1       5.9     02.04.2014 02:00
1         A1       8       02.04.2014 03:00
1         A1       7       02.04.2014 04:00
1         A1       12      02.04.2014 05:00
1         A2       5.6     02.04.2014 00:00
1         A2       10      02.04.2014 01:00
1         A2       5.9     02.04.2014 02:00
1         A2       8       02.04.2014 03:00
1         A2       7       02.04.2014 04:00
1         A2       12      02.04.2014 05:00
```

i.e. TableA have PrimaryKey from column dt, result table have primaryKey from columns dt and Code.
I try to TableA.Merge(TableB); than ResultTable.Merge(TableA) in loop. But in ResultTable I have only last merged table values.

Comment: @wudzik added comments in question

Comment: `select * into new table(your new table name) 
    from table1.col1,table1.col2,table2.col1,table2.col2;`(reqired columns)

Comment: @JihedJaouabi this is LINQ?

Comment: It's an sql query but you can convert it to LINQ
http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: @JihedJaouabi I've C# code

Comment: I'm not familiar with c# but maybe after converting sql to linq then use linq to dataset http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define one empty merge target table and merge all other tables into that merge table. So don't merge any tables upfront. Your code would look like this, with the datatable `merged` holding the end-result. In the [`Merge`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtk78t63%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method I use  `MissingSchemaAction.Ignore` to prevent a nullreferenceexception caused by possible mismatches between primarykey columns in the supplied datasets.

```
var one = BuildDataTable();
one.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { one.Columns["code"]}; 

var row = one.NewRow();
row["id"] = "1";
row["code"] = 1;
row["val"] = 5.6;
row["date_time"] = DateTime.Now;
one.Rows.Add(row);


var two = BuildDataTable();
two.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { two.Columns["date_time"] , two.Columns["code"]};

row = two.NewRow();
row["id"] = "1";
row["code"] = 2;
row["val"] = 3.0;
row["date_time"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
two.Rows.Add(row);

// merge table result
var merged = BuildDataTable();
merged.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { 
                        merged.Columns["date_time"] , 
                        merged.Columns["code"]};

// for each table call merge on our merged table
merged.Merge(one, true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore); 
merged.Merge(two, true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
// continue calling Merge until all tables are done
```

#### Helper method for building table

```
private DataTable BuildDataTable()
{
   var dt = new DataTable();
    //ParamId   | Code   | Val   | date_time
    dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("code", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("val", typeof(double));
    dt.Columns.Add("date_time", typeof(DateTime));
    return dt;
}
```